# Function on Chrome Extension Load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How do I fire a function on a Chrome extension load? I thought perhaps this was the solution but I implemented with no luck:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function callback)
```

Specifically, my goal is to run an API call as soon as a user clicks my extension's icon. Part of the API function is below:

```
function login() {
    formAdd = "";

    $.post("https://myurl",
    {
        ServerAction: "STEP4",
        ApiGuid: apikey
    },
    function(data, status){


    if (data == "Login failed.") {  

        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Login failed. Please input your API Key.";
    /*  previous(); */
        console.log("login bad");
    }
    else {

        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        data2 = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: @wOxxOm See edits above

Comment: Assuming this is in popup js file, simply add `login()` as the first statement in the file just like with any other page. Note, the popup is a separate page so to inspect it you need to rightclick it, then click inspect.